# Listener not firing off callback

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, listener

I have a class that implements a listener so that when another class that has an async tasks has been completed then the data can be returned with the use of this listener. The async task is being completed but the listener is not passing the data when it's obtained in the post execute function.

**Async Task**

```
Public class AdFetcher extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
{
private HTTPListener listener;

//sets the listeners
public AdFetcher(HTTPListener listener)
{
   this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;
    String responseString = null;
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
            out.close();
            responseString = out.toString();
        } else{
            //Closes the connection.
            response.getEntity().getContent().close();
            throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        //TODO Handle problems..
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //TODO Handle problems..
    }
    return responseString;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
{
    //Tries to deserialization and if there is an exception then its added to the Stack Trace.
    try
    {
        JSONObject data = new JSONObject(result);
        if(listener==null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        //Calls onComplete function in the class/Activity that implemented the listener.
        listener.onComplete(data);
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}

}
```

**Listener**

```
public interface HTTPListener{

/**
 * Callback function that must be implemented
 * to get result from HTTP worker thread.
 * @param result
 */
public void  onComplete (JSONObject result);

}//end HttpListener interface
```

**Class Implementing the listener**

```
public class AdManager implements HTTPListener
{
//will store the current context of the application.
private  Context context;
private Utility utils;
private String url;
private WebView client;
public AdManager(Context context,WebView client)
{
   this.client = client;
   this.context = context;
}

public void getAd()
{
    utils = new Utility();
    url =   utils.BuildUrl();
    new AdFetcher(this).execute(url);
}


public void  onComplete(JSONObject result)
{     
     try
     {   Log.e("RESULTS",result.getString("adtype"));
         if(result.getString("error") == "null")
         {

             if(result.getString("adtype") == "banner")
             {   //loads the banner image in the webview.

                 String html = "<a href=\""+result.getString("adclick_url")+"\"><img src=\""+result.getString("adimage")+"\"></a>";
                 String mime = "text/html";
                 String encoding = "utf-8";
                 client.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 client.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                 client.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, mime, encoding, null);


             }

         }

     }
     catch (JSONException e)
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

}
}
```

Comment: Is there any exception for this code  `JSONObject data = new JSONObject(result);`

Comment: Have You observed any exception? What does it mean ' listener is not passing the data'? Was listener called but with null data?

Comment: No exceptions were thrown.the onComplete function is not being called.